# Profile with spring-security doesn´t work

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization, profile

I´m using spring-security to validate at users in function its profiles, but my app doesn´t make it well, when I see the file log, it show me this:

> DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider:308 - User account is locked

In my form login I put the data well, but I never pass to other page, I´m always in the same page (form page), I introduce good or bad data

My code is:

file configuration spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/init" access="PROFILE_ADMINISTRATOR" />

        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/" 
            default-target-url="/init" 
            always-use-default-target='true'
            authentication-failure-url="/"/>

        <security:http-basic />

    </security:http>  

    <security:authentication-manager alias="autenticationManagerUserService">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
     </security:authentication-manager> 

     <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">

        <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="decisorDeRoles"/>
                <beans:ref bean="decisorDeAutenticacion"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="decisorDeRoles" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="PROFILE_"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="decisorDeAutenticacion" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>

    <beans:bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener"/>

</beans:beans>
```

class of UserDatailsService

```
@Service("userService")
public class SecurityAuthenticationProvider implements UserDetailsService
{
UserDao userDao = new UserDao ();

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername (String username) throws  UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException
    {
        User user = null;
        List<User> users = userDao.getUser (username);
        if (users.size () == 0)
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException ("");
        }
        else
        {
            user = users.get (0);
            user.setAuthorities (userDao.getProfileUser (username));
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

class UserDatails

```
public class User implements UserDetails
{    
    private List<GrantedAuthority> profiles;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private boolean enabled;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities ()
    {
        return profiles;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setAuthorities (List<? extends GrantedAuthority> profiles)
    {
        this.profiles = (List<GrantedAuthority>) profiles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword ()
    {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername ()
    {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired ()
    {
        return accountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked ()
    {
        return accountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired ()
    {
        return credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled ()
    {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setUsername (String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword (String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setAccountNonExpired (boolean accountNonExpired)
    {
        this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
    }

    public void setAccountNonLocked (boolean accountNonLocked)
    {
        this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
    }

    public void setCredentialsNonExpired (boolean credentialsNonExpired)
    {
        this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    public void setEnabled (boolean enabled)
    {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

class GrantedAuthority

```
public class Profile implements GrantedAuthority
{
    private String profile;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority ()
    {
        return profile;
    }

    public String getProfile ()
    {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile (String profile)
    {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

}
```

Class that I have created to simulate access to database (to obtain data)

```
public class UserDao
{

    public List<? extends GrantedAuthority> getProfileUser (String name)
    {
        List<GrantedAuthority> listGrantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> ();
        Profile profile = new Profile ();
        profile.setProfile ("PROFILE_ADMINISTRATOR");
        listGrantedAuthorities.add (profile);
        return listGrantedAuthorities;
    }

    public List<User> getUser (String name)
    {
        List<User> listUser = new ArrayList<User> ();
        User user = new User ();
        user.setUsername ("Admin");
        user.setPassword ("1234");
        // user.setAccountNonExpired (true);
        // user.setAccountNonLocked (true);
        // user.setCredentialsNonExpired (true);
        // user.setEnabled (true);
        listUser.add (user);

        return listUser;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your implementation of the `UserDetails` is flawed. The default value for a boolean is `false` so the method `isAccountNonLocked` returns false indicating the user is blocked.

Comment: sorry but I don´t understand it! If I uncomment the lines that are comments, I have the same mistake:
`DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider:308 - User account is locked`,
what can it be?

Comment: Spring Security uses those methods for checking, if they are wrongly implemented it will not work.

Comment: yes, that I know it, but I don´t know why it´s wrong. I think that it´s implemented well, no?

Comment: Why did you implement your own? Your PROFILE is nothing more then a different Role prefix which would work with the default implementation as is. What I don't see in your configuration where is your `UserDetailsService` configured?

Comment: I implemented "profile"  because I have to can assign a profile to an user and I thought that this form was the correct. "UserDatailsService" has implemented it in "SecurityAuthenticationProvider" implementing the "loadUserByUsername" method.

Comment: Either way the check that is done on the `isAccountNonLocked` method, if that returns `false` the message you state is printed. So there must be either something wrong in your implementation (i.e values aren't set correctly) or you haven't shown everything you have. However as I mentioned before, the code you have shown doesn't add anything the default already does so I'm still not sure why you have tried to create your own implementation (unless your `Profile` is more then you showed here).

Comment: I have already corrected the mistake, I have changed the user class and the profile class and I do all operations into the SecurityAuthenticationProvider class.

Thanks you very much for your help, I have been great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue while working with rest oauth2 spring security.

**SOLUTION**

you need to make few changes in your class which implements UserDetails (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails),  in your case its the user class.

For the following overriding methods isAccountNonLocked(), isAccountNonExpired(), isEnabled(), isCredentialsNonExpired() 
change the retrun type to true (by default its false).

make note that these all methods should have a logic to return true or false depending on your requirement but to make your code work i am suggesting you to return true for all the mentioned methods.